# XCM Reserve Transfer Between AssetHub (Rococo) is Unroutable

Tags: xcm, error, rococo, transfer, cross-chain

I am testing transferring ROC between AssetHub and a Parachain. The HRMP channels are already open but when I submit try the following XCM Message:
[image]

I get this error:

```json
    [
      {
        type: "docs",
        value: "Execution of an XCM message was attempted."
      },
      {
        type: "xcm:v3:traits:Outcome",
        type_name: "xcm::latest::Outcome",
        value: {
          Incomplete: {
            col0: {
              proof_size: 6196,
              ref_time: 683414000
            },
            col1: {
              Unroutable: "NULL"
            }
          }
        },
        name: "outcome"
      }
    ]
```

The current XCM configuration for the runtime is: (link to code: [here](https://github.com/t3rn/t3rn))

```rust
        // Means for transacting assets on this chain.
    pub type LocalAssetTransactor = CurrencyAdapter<
        // Use this currency:
        Balances,
        // Use this currency when it is a fungible asset matching the given location or name:
        IsConcrete<SelfLocation>,
        // Do a simple punn to convert an AccountId32 MultiLocation into a native chain account ID:
        LocationToAccountId,
        // Our chain's account ID type (we can't get away without mentioning it explicitly):
        AccountId,
        // We don't track any teleports.
        (),
    >;
    
    pub type TrustBackedAssetsConvertedConcreteId =
        assets_common::TrustBackedAssetsConvertedConcreteId<AssetsPalletLocation, Balance>;
    
    /// Means for transacting assets besides the native currency on this chain.
    pub type FungiblesTransactor = FungiblesAdapter<
        // Use this fungibles implementation:
        Assets,
        // Use the asset registry for lookups
        TrustBackedAssetsConvertedConcreteId,
        //ConvertedConcreteAssetId<AssetIdForTrustBackedAssets, Balance, AssetRegistry, JustTry>,
        // Convert an XCM MultiLocation into a local account id:
        LocationToAccountId,
        // Our chain's account ID type (we can't get away without mentioning it explicitly):
        AccountId,
        // We only want to allow teleports of known assets. We use non-zero issuance as an indication
        // that this asset is known.
        LocalMint<parachains_common::impls::NonZeroIssuance<AccountId, Assets>>,
        // The account to use for tracking teleports.
        CheckingAccount,
    >;
    pub type AssetTransactors = (LocalAssetTransactor, FungiblesTransactor);

    pub type Barrier = (
       TakeWeightCredit,
       AllowKnownQueryResponses<PolkadotXcm>,
       AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom<Everything>,
       AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<ParentOrParentsExecutivePlurality>,
       AllowSubscriptionsFrom<ParentOrSiblings>,
    );

    impl xcm_executor::Config for XcmConfig {
        type Aliasers = Nothing;
        type AssetClaims = PolkadotXcm;
        type AssetExchanger = ();
        type AssetLocker = ();
        type AssetTransactor = AssetTransactors;
        type AssetTrap = PolkadotXcm;
        type Barrier = Barrier;
        type CallDispatcher = RuntimeCall;
        type FeeManager = ();
        type IsReserve = NativeAsset;
        type IsTeleporter = (
            NativeAsset,
            // IsForeignConcreteAsset<FromSiblingParachain<parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>>>,
        );
        type MaxAssetsIntoHolding = MaxAssetsIntoHolding;
        type MessageExporter = ();
        type OriginConverter = XcmOriginToTransactDispatchOrigin;
        type PalletInstancesInfo = AllPalletsWithSystem;
        type ResponseHandler = PolkadotXcm;
        type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
        type SafeCallFilter = Everything;
        type SubscriptionService = PolkadotXcm;
        type Trader = UsingComponents<WeightToFee, RelayLocation, AccountId, Balances, ()>;
        type UniversalAliases = Nothing;
        type UniversalLocation = UniversalLocation;
        type Weigher = FixedWeightBounds<UnitWeightCost, RuntimeCall, MaxInstructions>;
        type XcmSender = XcmRouter;
     }
    
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
        parameter_types! {
        pub ReachableDest: Option<MultiLocation> = Some(Parent.into());
    }
    
    impl pallet_xcm::Config for Runtime {
        type AdminOrigin = EnsureRoot<crate::AccountId>;
        // type AdminOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
        type AdvertisedXcmVersion = pallet_xcm::CurrentXcmVersion;
        type Currency = Balances;
        type CurrencyMatcher = ();
        // We support local origins dispatching XCM executions in principle...
        type ExecuteXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<RuntimeOrigin, LocalOriginToLocation>;
        type MaxLockers = ConstU32<8>;
        type MaxRemoteLockConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<0>;
        // type MaxRemoteLockConsumers = ConstU32<0>;
        #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
        type ReachableDest = ReachableDest;
        type RemoteLockConsumerIdentifier = ();
        // type RemoteLockConsumerIdentifier = ();
        type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
        type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
        type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
        // We want to disallow users sending (arbitrary) XCMs from this chain.
        type SendXcmOrigin = EnsureXcmOrigin<RuntimeOrigin, ()>;
        type SovereignAccountOf = LocationToAccountId;
        type TrustedLockers = ();
        type UniversalLocation = UniversalLocation;
        type Weigher = FixedWeightBounds<UnitWeightCost, RuntimeCall, MaxInstructions>;
        // FIXME: Replace with benchmarked weight info
        type WeightInfo = pallet_xcm::TestWeightInfo;
        // ... but disallow generic XCM execution. As a result only teleports and reserve transfers are allowed.
        type XcmExecuteFilter = Nothing;
        type XcmExecutor = XcmExecutor<XcmConfig>;
        type XcmReserveTransferFilter = Everything;
        type XcmRouter = XcmRouter;
        type XcmTeleportFilter = Everything;
    
        const VERSION_DISCOVERY_QUEUE_SIZE: u32 = 100;
    }
```

Any guidance on what causes the error and how I can make it work?

Comment: The error you get in PolkadotJS UI is Unroutable?

Comment: Yup, that's the one! @AlexBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be fixed after updating the configuration of the following:

**FungiblesTransactor**

```
pub type FungiblesTransactor = FungiblesAdapter<
Assets,
ConvertedRegisteredAssetId<
    AssetIdForTrustBackedAssets,
    Balance,
    AsAssetMultiLocation<AssetIdForTrustBackedAssets, AssetRegistry>,
    JustTry,
>,
LocationToAccountId,
AccountId,
PlaceholderAccount,>;
```

**Barrier**

```
 pub type Barrier = TrailingSetTopicAsId<(
    TakeWeightCredit,
    AllowKnownQueryResponses<PolkadotXcm>,
    WithComputedOrigin<
        (
            AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom<Everything>,
            AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<ParentOrParentsExecutivePlurality>,
            AllowSubscriptionsFrom<ParentOrSiblings>,
        ),
        UniversalLocation,
        ConstU32<8>,
    >,
)>
```

**IsReserve**

```
pub type Reserves = (NativeAsset, ReserveAssetsFrom<AssetHubLocation>);
```

ROC will appear on the parachain if the asset `MultiLocation` is registered with an asset

Answer (score 0):

It's because the missing xcm version in Rococo AssetHub.

Please check this issue: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/1640

You can ask Rococo for help.